# Qt signal emits in a strange way

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qprocess

I've got a following code for pushbutton:

```
emit busySignal();
QString program = "cmd";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "";
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
myProcess->write("cd C:\\Qt\\5.11.2\\mingw53_32\\bin\\\n");
myProcess->waitForBytesWritten();
myProcess->write("windeployqt C:\\Users\\BRSLV\\Desktop\\qml_collect_project\n");
myProcess->waitForBytesWritten();
myProcess->waitForFinished();
myProcess->close();
emit readySignal();
```

and following qml code:

```
Model
{
    id : model
    onBusySignal: busy.running = true
    onReadySignal: busy.running = false
}
BusyIndicator {
    id: busy
    running: false

}
```

the problem is - signals do not work as i expect them to for some reason: busySignal() affects on qml only after QProcess is finished. Can someone tell me how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The waitForXXX methods are blocking, so they will freeze the GUI, preventing asynchronous tasks such as the transmission of signals from being executed, so the solution is to use signals to know when to notify that the task is finished.

On the other hand, your code can be reduced using `setWorkingDirectory()` that replaces `cd` command.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

class ProcessManager: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ProcessManager(QObject *parent=nullptr):
        QObject(parent)
    {
        connect(&m_process, QOverload<int>::of(&QProcess::finished), this, &ProcessManager::readySignal);
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void start_process(){
        emit busySignal();
        const QString program = "cmd";
        m_process.setWorkingDirectory("C:\\Qt\\5.11.2\\mingw53_32\\bin");
        m_process.start(program, {"windeployqt", "C:\\Users\\BRSLV\\Desktop\\qml_collect_project"});
    }
signals:
    void busySignal();
    void readySignal();
private:
    QProcess m_process;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    qmlRegisterType<ProcessManager>("com.utils", 1, 0, "ProcessManager");
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

import com.utils 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ProcessManager{
        id: pm
        onBusySignal: busy.running = true
        onReadySignal:  busy.running = false
    }
    BusyIndicator {
        id: busy
        running: false
    }
    Button{
        anchors.top: busy.bottom
        text: "start process"
        onClicked: pm.start_process()
    }
}
```